# Filtering in phpspreadsheet

Tags: excel, filter, phpspreadsheet

I'm trying to filter my spreadsheet with phpspreadsheet. I use setAutoFilter and want everything from column 2 to row E. So I have tried the way test, but I get everything, including column1 to row AMK.

What am I doing wrong?

```
$inputFileName = public_path() . '\barcode.xlsx';
    $inputFileType = IOFactory::identify($inputFileName);

    $reader = IOFactory::createReader('Xlsx');


    //$reader->setReadFilter(new MyReadFilter());

    $spreadsheet = $reader->load($inputFileName);

    //$spreadsheet = IOFactory::load($inputFileName);
    $sheetData = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setAutoFilter('B1:E20')->toArray(null, true, true, true);
```

Comment: I'm not all that familiar with phpspreadhseet, so I'm not going to post this as an answer, but you're creating a new instance of an object `MyReadFilter()` for `setReaderFilter` method and you haven't even posted your class / prototype for the `MyReadFilter()` object Additionally, the standard `ActiveFilter` definition seems to be `$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setAutoFilter('A1:E20');` which doesn't match what you're doing (what I'm hinting at, you're referencing a Filter Object(?) and not a Range)

Comment: I left that in to show what I've already tried. The solution with this filter can be found in the documentation. However, I get the following message when I want to use setReaders:

Method 'setReadFilter' not found in \ PhpOffice \ PhpSpreadsheet \ Reader \ IReader less ... (Ctrl + F1)
Referenced method is not found in subject class.